# Date in format DD MMM YYYY where 1st letter is upper case

Tags: groovy

Need help - I need enter date in date picker via automation script written in Geb & Spock. Date format expected is `DD MMM YYYY` where 1st letter of month is in upper case. Here is what I have tried:

```
String sDate = String.format(start.toString("dd MMM YYYY")); 
String oDate = sDate.substring(0,2) + sDate.substring(3,6).toUppercase() + sDate.substring(0,4);
```

Comment: Show us what you already tried.

Comment: String sDate = String.format(start.toString("dd MMM YYYY"));
String oDate = sDate.substring(0, 2)+sDate.substring(3, 6).toUppercase()+sDate.substring(0, 4);

Comment: Code is better in the question where it can be formatted... Can you edit your question and put it there?

Comment: What is the type of `start`?

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, the first letter of the month is already in upper case, but here's how you can do it:

```
def date = new Date()
def formattedDate = date.format('dd MMM YYYY').with {
    new StringBuilder()
        .append(getAt(0..2))
        .append(getAt(3).toUpperCase())
        .append(getAt(4..-1))
        .toString()
}
```

Comment: Only in English. In Swedish, day of week and month is not capitalized by defaul.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one-liner:

```
new Date().format('dd MMM YYYY').replaceFirst(/\b[a-z]/) { it.toUpperCase() }

assert "19 Jan 2016" == "19 jan 2016".replaceFirst(/\b[a-z]/) { it.toUpperCase() }
```

The `replaceFirst` use a regex to match the first **leading** lowercase letter and change it to uppercase.

**Regex Breakout**

```
\b     # matches an empty space between \w and \W (see below)
[a-z]  # matches a single lowercase letter
```

---

**NOTE** the `\b` matches the empty space between a *regex word character* (one of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` shorted as `\w`) and a character **not** in that group (in regex language `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` or shorted as `\W` ). **e.g.** A literal space `' '` belongs to the not-regex-word group `\W`.

So if the `month` has already the first letter capitalized (why your locale expect this) nothing unexpected happens:

```
assert "19 Jan 2016" == "19 Jan 2016".replaceFirst(/\b[a-z]/) { it.toUpperCase() }
```

Without the `\b` instead this is the result:

```
assert "19 JAn 2016" == "19 Jan 2016".replaceFirst(/[a-z]/) { it.toUpperCase() }
```

Answer (score 0):

For complete month name with first letter uppercase

```
string sDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
string oDate = sDate.Replace(sDate.Split(' ')[1], char.ToUpper(sDate.Split(' ')[1][0]) + sDate.Split(' ')[1].Substring(1));
```

For short month name with first letter uppercase

```
string sDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
string oDate = sDate.Replace(sDate.Split(' ')[1][0], char.ToUpper(sDate.Split(' ')[1][0]);
```

For Culture based date

```
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT"));
```